# Translating lame arguments to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, file-conversion, lame

I'm trying to translate a lame command to ffmpeg, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing.
The first command is not applicable for all audio formats because LAME can't handle them. The second command yields a file that differs 1 kb from the first, but I figured that might be due to frame rate corrections and rounding. Anyway.

Are the two following commands synonymous?

```
lame -q 9 -b 16 input.wav output.mp3
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -compression_level 9 -b:a 16k output.mp3
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libmp3lame-1

Comment: Yes, but I get conflicting info from the site https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3 where `-q:a` is used instead of `-compression_level`. But because I get mp3s with another size, I'm not sure if `-compression_level` is the correct translation for `LAME`'s `-q`.

Comment: It says clearly (table) that `-q:a` corresponds to lame's `-V` (VBR) and on  the page I linked you have the lame arguments between parentheses. Your first command uses a 6k bitrate vs. 16k (CBR) in the 2nd, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. I corrected it. Also, I misread big time. I guess I did it right. Thanks for the help.